# Powershell output formatting issue

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, windows-server-2008-r2

So I'm working on an inventory script for our servers and have hit a roadblock at the storage.  Here's the code:

```
$StorageInfo=Get-WmiObject win32_volume | Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 3 -and $_.Label -ne 'System Reserved' -and $_.DriveLetter -ne $null}

$DriveLetters=$StorageInfo | Select-Object DriveLetter | Sort-Object DriveLetter | ft -HideTableHeaders
$DriveNames=$StorageInfo | Sort-Object DriveLetter | Select-Object Label | ft -HideTableHeaders
$DriveCapacity=$StorageInfo |Sort-Object DriveLetter | ForEach-Object {[Math]::Truncate($_.Capacity / 1GB)}

$DriveLetters

$DriveNames

$DriveCapacity
```

The data that comes from that is as follows:

```
C:                                                                                                                                                                                                  
D:                                                                                                                                                                                                  
E:                                                                                                                                                                                                  
F:                                                                                                                                                                                                  
G:                                                                                                                                                                                                  

OSDisk                                                                                                                                                                                              
Data                                                                                                                                                                                                
SQL Data                                                                                                                                                                                            
SQL Logs                                                                                                                                                                                            
SQL Temp                                                                                                                                                                                            

232
97
97
97
48
```

I'd like to be able to format it as such:

```
C:\, OSDisk - 232gb
D:\, Data - 97gb
C:\, SQLData - 97gb
C:\, SQLLogs - 97gb
C:\, SQLTemp - 97gb
```

...and I can't quite figure this out.  Can anyone offer assistance?

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_volume -Filter "DriveType=3 AND Label <> 'System Reserved' AND DriveLetter IS NOT NULL" | 
Select-Object Name,Label,@{Name='CapacityGB';E={[Math]::Truncate($_.Capacity / 1GB)}}
```

If you want the exact output as described (thanks Ansgar):

```
Get-WmiObject win32_volume -Filter "DriveType=3 AND Label <> 'System Reserved' AND DriveLetter IS NOT NULL" | ForEach-Object{
    "{0}, {1} - {2}gb" -f $_.Name,$_.Label,([Math]::Truncate($_.Capacity/1GB))
}
```

Comment: Use `"{0}\, {1} - {2}" -f (DriveLetter,Label,@{Name='...})` instead of `Select-Object ...` to get the particular output format.

Comment: I'll be working on this again at the end of this week.  I'll let you know how it goes then.

Thanks for the responses, guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
$logfile = <log file path>
 $path = <path of the file to which we need to sort> 
$Array = gc $path
 $Count = $Array.Count
 for($i=0; $i -le $Count; $i++) 
{ $a =$Array[$i]
 $i = $i+1
 write-output $i | out-file $logfile
 $a+=" "+ $Array[$i] 
$i = $i+1 
write-output $i | out-file  $logfile 
$a+=" "+ $Array[$i]
 write-output $i | out-file $logfile 
$New = $a | Select-Object -Unique #| out-file $logfile }
```